# RelativeLayout match_parent not working

Tags: android, xml, layout

> ```
>  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:background="@drawable/ic_shade"
> android:layout_height="match_parent" >   
>  <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
>     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>      android:gravity="center"
>      android:textSize="54sp"
>     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>     android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>     android:text="مبروك \nلقد ربحت كوبون"/>  
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

What happens, it doesnt take entire width/height and i dont see the background on entire page.I am using the activity to be transparent.
Below is code for activity, however  if i add

> ```
>  < item name="android:windowFullscreen ">true</item>
> ```

to the below part it works.. but i dont want it to do it because its resizing my previous activity.

> ```
>    <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
>     <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
>     <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
>     <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
>     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
>     <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
>     <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
> </style>
> <!-- Application t
> ```

Answer (score 0):

your `textview` is filling the whole screen, change `layout_height` and `layout_width` attributes of your text view to `wrap_content`. then textview will be in center and background will appear on entire screen